# ViewController inside another View Controller with Swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uisegmentedcontrol

I have segmented button control in view controller. 
The problem is that when I click on the "Data 3" tab, it goes to Data3 View Controller. 
I would like to be Data3 View Controller shows inside ViewController-1 UI (Under segmented control button.)

[image]

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)


let innerPage: Data3 = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “Data3”) as! MediaPack
self.present(innerPage, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish that task you either use UiPageViewController or ContainerView that contain your viewController3.
Find below link to implement

**UiPageViewController**
http://samwize.com/2015/10/13/how-to-create-uipageviewcontroller-in-storyboard-in-container-view/

**ContainerView**
https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/

Comment: Yes @Satinder, I will look at your links. Thanks :)

Comment: When I try Container View way, I got error.  self.add(asChildViewController: viewController) . ViewController-1 has no member 'add'. Bro @Satinder

Comment: private lazy var data3ViewController: Data3 = {
        // Load Storyboard
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        
        // Instantiate View Controller
        var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “Data3”) as! Data3
        
        // Add View Controller as Child View Controller
        self.add(asChildViewController: viewController)
        
        return viewController
    }()

Comment: Instead of self.add(asChildViewController:viewController)
Use this self.addChildViewController(viewController)
There are some syntax error don't copy paste code just write it

Comment: Bro @Satinder, when I click on Data 3 button, child view controller shows. But, it covers the segmented button :( . Not under the segmented button. How to do it bro?

Comment: The frame of container view would incorrect , just recheck frame of container view and segment control.